# onClick on div is not working with the react js

Tags: reactjs

## Child component Code

```
import { Avatar, Modal, Button } from "flowbite-react";
import { HiPlay, HiCheck, HiCheckCircle  } from 'react-icons/hi';

export default function SearchResult({ influencer, imagePath }, props) {
    return <div key={influencer?.id} className="flex my-3 w-full cursor-pointer" onClick={() => { props.click}}>
    <Avatar
        size="xs"
        img={imagePath + influencer?.im}
        rounded={true}
    />
    <div className="flex w-[88%]">
    <div className="px-2 text-gray600 text-text-sm font-semibold">{influencer?.social_user_name}</div>
    <div className="text-gray600 text-text-sm">{influencer?.social_name}</div>
    </div>
    <div className="mt-[5px] mx-2 min-w-[16px]">{influencer?.verified ? <HiCheckCircle fill="#1C64F2"  /> : ' ' }</div>
    <div className="mt-[5px] mx-2 min-w-[16px]">{influencer?.isTrending ? <HiCheck fill="#1C64F2"  />: ' ' }</div>
</div>
}
```

## Parent component Code

```
const showSearchResult = () => {
        return topTrendList.map((influencer) => {
            return  <SearchResult imagePath={topImagePath} click={() => handleSearchInput(influencer)} influencer={influencer}></SearchResult>
        })
    }
// click function
const handleSearchInput = (item) => {
        console.log(item);
    }
```

Using react functional component to handle click the div
added the function of click

If i remove arrow function from SearchResult it called multiple times. If arrow function added it's not calling the handleSearchInput function.

Answer (score 0):

Child component

Mistake that you were doing: You were calling the `click` function in the wrong way.

Your code: `onClick={() => { props.click}}`

Correct code: `onClick={() => { props.click()}}` or `onClick = {props.click}`

```
export default function SearchResult({ influencer, imagePath, click }) {
  return (
    <div
      key={influencer?.id}
      className="flex my-3 w-full cursor-pointer"
      onClick={() => click()}
    >
      {" "}
      <Avatar size="xs" img={imagePath + influencer?.im} rounded={true} />{" "}
      {influencer?.social_user_name} {influencer?.social_name}{" "}
      {influencer?.verified ? ":" : ""} {influencer?.isTrending ? ":" : ""}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's still not working tried both the ways.

Comment: attaching the function which is called on click 
const handleSearchInput = (item) => {
        console.log(item);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, regarding your code, you should not use `click` as you didn't declare this name before declare it in the Child component.

Secondly, the way you declare the input parameters of the Child is not correct. It should look like this: `SearchResult({ influencer, imagePath, click })`.